# How to count an amount of vertices

Tags: geometry

I am not strong in math, quite not strong to be absolutely honest. I had been drawing different geometrical figures of boredom and one intrested me.

[image: image is here]

Here on image are 81 vertices (I counted, lol) - how to calculate it with math, what formula is for this? And what area of mathematics is solving problems like this?

Comment: There are actually 85 vertices in the image.

Comment: Sorry, even so :) I missed.

Comment: There are lots of ways. One way is count the number of vertices in each of the two types of rows, then multiply by the respective row-type counts and add the results.

Comment: "*What area of mathematics is solving problems like this*" uhm... middle school geometry for problems on the level you describe, but for much more complicated shapes i suppose you could call it combinatorial geometry.  As for a method to count, you should know the number of vertices on a $1\times 1$ square is $4$ and in general on an $n\times m$ rectangle are $(n+1)\times (m+1)$.  Look at the points in the center of the squares separately than on the corners of the grid to see there are $7^2+6^2=49+36=85$ vertices

Comment: 7 rows×7vertices=49 and 6rows×6vertices=36 which sum up to 85

Comment: If you want more complicated methods which can be used for more complicated problems, see for example [Pick's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) and [Ehrhart polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial).  If you do approach as such, note that you will want to picture your axes going diagonally, not horizontally/vertically in order to account for the vertices in the middle of your larger squares, treating the smaller squares as our base unit.

Comment: You can also count the amount of edges and faces, and use the Euler characteristic formula, that $\chi(\textrm{plane})=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well we have $7$ rows with $7$ vertices so we get $49$ vertices from that. We also have $6$ rows with $6$ vertices which gives us $36$ vertices. Now if we add these two sums together we get $36 + 49 = 85$.